# Assigning values to a query result already set up with a foreign key

Tags: django

I have a database of exhibition listings related by foreign key to a database of venues where they take place. Django templates access the venue information in the query results through `listing.venue.name`, `listing.venue.url`, and so on.

However, some exhibitions take place in temporary venues, and that information is stored in the same database, in what would be `listing.temp_venue_url` and such. Because it seems wasteful and sad to put conditionals all over the templates, I want to move the info for temporary venues to where the templates are expecting info for regular venues. This didn't work:

```
def transfer_temp_values(listings):
    for listing in listings:
        if listing.temp_venue:
            listing.venue = Venue
            listing.venue.name = listing.temp_venue
            listing.venue.url = listing.temp_venue_url
            listing.venue.state = listing.temp_venue_state
            listing.venue.location = listing.temp_venue_location
```

The error surprised me:

```
ValueError at /[...]/
Cannot assign "<class 'myproject.gsa.models.Venue'>": "Exhibition.venue" must be a "Venue" instance.
```

I rather thought it was. How do I go about accomplishing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message is because you have assigned the *class* `Venue` to the listing, rather than an instance of it. You need to call the class to get an instance:

```
listing.venue = Venue()
```

Comment: Thank you, Daniel. (facepalms)